# OSX App development with finder integration

Tags: macos, cloud

I want to develop an app which will works like Dropbox,GoogleDrive with the integration of finder. I have a server which stores metadata of files and folders and I want to show the same files/folders structure in finder. I don't want to download the files locally for showing files in finder I want to show all files and folders structure in finder. If anyone did like this then please suggest me some links or any sample code.

Thanks in Advance